# Laravel 5 steam condenser

Tags: php, laravel, steam

**Composer.json**

```
    "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
            "files": [
                "vendor/koraktor/steam-condenser/lib/steam-condenser.php"
            ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
```

**HomeController**

```
    public function index()
    {
        $server = new SourceServer('80.67.11.46:27025');
        try {
          $server->rconAuth('abc123');
          echo $server->rconExec('status');
        }
        catch(RCONNoAuthException $e) {
          trigger_error('Could not authenticate with the game server.',
            E_USER_ERROR);

        }
    }
```

I have updated the composer after adding, dump-autoload and tried all the solutions i can find with namespaces and so on.

But can't still use the steam condenser classes, any solution for this ?

Comment: What's the error? Are you unable to authenticate or just unable to use the library?

Comment: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\SourceServer' not found

, error on the row with $server = new SourceServer

Answer (score 1):

The error **Class 'App\Http\Controllers\SourceServer' not found** denotes the fact that you're inside the `App\Http\Controllers` namespace and as such it will try to find the `SourceServer` class within that namespace. Prepend `\` to your class name to call it in a global context:

```
$server = new \SourceServer('80.67.11.46:27025');
```

Or add this after the namespace declaration at the top of your controller:

```
use SourceServer;
```

And remove the class mapping from `composer.json` because it's not needed. You can read up more on how namespaces work in the [PHP Namespaces Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php).